# premature end of file while parsing an xml file on android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, xom

I'm trying to read an xml file on from an android app using [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) as the XML library. I'm trying this:

```
Builder parser = new Builder();
Document doc = parser.build(context.openFileInput(XML_FILE_LOCATION));
```

But I'm getting `nu.xom.ParsingException: Premature end of file.` even when the file is empty.

I need to parse a very simple `XML` file, and I'm ready to use another library instead of XOM so let me know if there's a better one. or just a solution to the problem using XOM.

In case it helps, I'm using [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) to get the parser.

------Edit-----

PS: The purpose of this wasn't to parse an empty file, the file just happened to be empty on the first run which showed this error.

Comment: What is the data in the XML file? Seems like you are missing at least on close tag `</tag>`.

Comment: (Sorry, I tend to focus on the code more than the verbal descriptions.) Parsing an empty file seems silly. Perhaps you should check the file's size before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow [this](http://marc.info/?l=xom-interest&m=122486269712461&w=2) post to the end, it seems that this has to do with `xerces` and the fact that its an empty file, and they didn't reach a solution on `xerces` side.

So I handled the issue as follows:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    Builder parser = new Builder();
    doc = parser.build(context.openFileInput(XML_FILE_LOCATION));
}catch (ParsingException ex) { //other catch blocks are required for other exceptions.
   //fails to open the file with a parsing error.
   //I create a new root element and a new document.
   //I fill them with xml data (else where in the code) and save them.
    Element root = new Element("root");
    doc = new Document(root);       
}
```

And then I can do whatever I want with `doc`. and you can add extra checks to make sure that the cause is really an empty file (like check the file size as indicated by one of sam's comments on the question).

Comment: Rather than catching an exception (I'm sure other scenarios might also throw a `ParsingException`), I wonder if it wouldn't be less ugly to somehow check if the xml file isn't 'empty'. Perhaps you can check the [`size()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#size%28%29) of the underlying `FileChannel`, or [`available()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29) bytes from the `FileInputStream`?

Comment: Whups, not sure how I overlooked that. :/ Just wanted to make sure you were aware of a slightly more 'clean' approach.

Comment: yea .. srry, I didn't have time to write the clean approach, it was 3 am here & I didn't want to leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

An empty file is not a well-formed XML document. Throwing a ParsingException is the right thing to do here.